# ReactiveMongo connect with MongoConnectionOptions

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I was connecting to my MongoDB using `MongoConnectionOptions` in reactivemongo version `0.15.x`. Now I updated to `0.20.11`.

The `apply()` function of the `MongoConnectionOptions` companion object is deprecated now. The deprecation warning says to use the constructor of `MongoConnectionOptions`. Unfortunately this constructor is package-private.

I do not want to use the deprecated apply function mainly because my scala compiler options do not allow warnings. (And I really don't want to change this).

The official documentation only explains the deprecated version: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html

How can I still connect to the database using connection options?

Comment: The version  0.1.5 or 0.2.11 you mentioned don't exist. The connection option can be specified in the URI (see connection documentation).

Comment: @cchantep sorry, I got the versions wrong. I updated them in the original question. For the URL: I need to assemble it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory `MongoConnectionOptions(..)` will be refactored in coming next major release 1.0.x.

Anyway, you can using `.default` + `.copy(..)`:

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.MongoConnectionOptions

MongoConnectionOptions.default.copy(appName = "Foo")
```

Moreover, options can be prepared (from config file or programmatically) as URI string.

```scala
val host = "localhost"
val port = 27017

reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection.connect(s"mongodb://${host}:${port}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following syntax and works fine for me:

```
val host = "localhost"
val port = "27017"
val db_name = "test"
val mongoUri = "mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db_name
val driver = new AsyncDriver
val database = for {
  uri <- MongoConnection.fromString(mongoUri)
  con <- driver.connect(uri)
  dn <- Future(uri.db.get)
  db <- con.database(dn)
} yield db

val bsonCollection: Future[BSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection(collectionName))
```